# MvvmCross xamarin : Send data from activity to viewmodel

Tags: android, xamarin, nfc, mvvmcross

I receive an nfc intent in my activity, after getting the string from nfc record, I want to pass it to a function in my viewmodel.

problem:
I want to be able to do this:
mViewmodel.processString("my string");

how do get the viewmodel instance?
or is there a better way to send that intent to viewmodel to get data from it and proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MVVMCross Messenger](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/messenger). Using MVVMCross Messenger you can do weak subscription and send and receive the messages from anywhere in the app.